# element select validation error

Tags: html, validation, select, element

I am confused as how to validate this strip of code in HTML5:

```
<select onChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
                                           
                <option value="">                 Choose Your State or Jurisdiction               </option>
                                           
                <option value="allaw.htm">Alabama </option>
                <option value="aklaw.htm">Alaska </option>
                (and so on for all states)
```

Which gives me a dropdown box of all the states. The error I get in validation is "text not allowed in element select in this context"

Could someone please point out how to validate this? Do I change the element select to something else?

Thanks a lot!

Gordon

Comment: You'll probably need to add "http://" to the URLs for this to work